# best possible index on this situation

Tags: sql-server, index, nonclustered-index

```
create table #testing(id int, name varchar(50))
go

Insert Into #testing
Values(231, 'fasd')

Insert Into #testing
Values(232, 'dsffd')

Insert Into #testing
Values(233, 'xas')

Insert Into #testing
Values(234, 'asdasd')

create table #testing2(id int, name varchar(50))
go
Insert Into #testing(id)
Values(231)

Insert Into #testing(id)
Values(232)

Insert Into #testing(id)
Values(233)

Insert Into #testing(id)
Values(234)
go

update m
set name = x.name
from #testing2 m
join #testing x  
on m.id = x.id
Where m.name is null
```

Without an index on #testing and #testing2

[image]

index on id column on both #testing and #testing2

[image]

index is

```
create nonclustered index ix_test1 on #testing1(id) include (name)
create nonclustered index ix_test1 on #testing2(id)
```

[image]

What would be the best possible index on this situation? Is it right to not have an index on #testing(name) because the write/update would be slower?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to perform the update once or on a regular basis? If the update on million rows is done once, then the best solution is to create a temp column "processed" on #testing2 table of bit (int,tinyint) which will serve as your null filter. The index on bit or int columns works a lot more optimal than on varchar. Also, having 2 type of values on index definition (0 for null 1 for not null) will be very fast.

Keep your indexes and add the second index and you will have the following Plan if you change the filtering options in the query on "processed" column as it is marked in the picture below with the plan:

```
create nonclustered index ix_test1 on testing2(processed, id)
```

[image: Exec plan]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the plans I would just drop the index on the #testing2 table as it's not doing anything for you.  With more data is might, but your sample tables are so small that SQL won't use it.

Comment: just a sample table. The actual table contains million rows.

Comment: In that case, if you're searching for nulls only a filtered index may make more sense. Filtered indexes come with some baggage though... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

Comment: Then I'd use a filtered index WHERE name IS NULL as that'll help a lot.

Comment: Filter index would be risky because he is updating the name column, which would then result in updates to the filter index too. @EmmanBangis: What is the size of these tables in your system and how many % rows have name IS NULL?